# How to calculate condition find the difference between two DateTime in minute in R

Tags: sql, r, datetime, difference, minute

I simulate data and DateTime is the date type from the database. I want to calculate the **difference of minutes between two DateTime** and find **average times to integer or decimal from the group.**
It calculates with an only confirmation.

maybe similar to this output data frame.

and this is my expectation graph. Orange color is deny grom group1

[image]

How can I do it? Thank you for coming.

Comment: Could you include sample of expected output in your question?

Comment: @RaV I edit my question to show my output expect. Did you understand?

Comment: I think you are looking for `difftime` function, see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/difftime . This will give you the difference. For the average, simply use the `dplyr` package to group by the grouping var. So for example your code will look like: `df %>% mutate(difference - difftime(date1, date2, unit = "hours") )%>% group_by(group)  %>% mutate(average = mean(difference))`. For graphing you might use summarise rather than mutate.

Comment: @Uren you keep on building the example. At this point it's quite requiring to keep up. Please, check out my answer and find out if it is enough to solve your problem or ask some subquestions in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this with use of `dplyr` and `ggplot2` packages:
Additionaly, you can use `lubridate` package, if your dates are strings.

To get differences and averages:

```
library(dplyr)
#load if you need to convert strings to dates
library(lubridate)

#df as in example, check 'Data' below
df_new <- df %>%
#counting differences in minutes
  mutate(difference = difftime(ymd_hms(date1), ymd_hms(date2), unit = "mins")) %>%
#grouping dates by 'abc' group
  group_by(group1) %>%
#counting average difference for every 'abc' group in minutes
  mutate(average = mean(difference))
```

To make plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

#passing summarized data to ggplot to create a plot and choosing aesthetics / dimensions to be ploted
ggplot(df_new, aes(y = avg_diff, x = group1, fill = group2)) +
#choosing type of plot
  geom_col() +
#flipping x and y axis
  coord_flip() +
#choosing colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "orange"))
```

[image: Result plot]

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("2020-04-05 11:51:51",
                           "2020-04-06 13:55:16",
                           "2020-04-06 14:26:56",
                           "2020-04-06 14:35:05",
                           "2020-04-06 14:36:00",
                           "2020-04-06 14:36:31",
                           "2020-04-06 14:36:31",
                           "2020-04-04 19:00:38",
                           "2020-04-05 21:22:23"),
                 date2 = c("2020-04-05 10:10:23",
                           "2020-04-06 11:41:20",
                           "2020-04-06 14:25:58",
                           "2020-04-06 14:26:03",
                           "2020-04-06 14:32:02",
                           "2020-04-06 14:33:35",
                           "2020-04-06 14:33:35",
                           "2020-04-04 18:30:29",
                           "2020-04-05 21:21:46"),
                 group1 = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                 group2 = c("accept", "accept", "accept", "denny", "denny", "accept", "accept", "denny", "denny"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: thank you. but sorry for my mistake. I write not clearly.